# How to fix error into my docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a some code into my docker-compose file. Example below:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  api.gw:
    image: ocelotapigw
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/OcelotApiGw/Dockerfile

  catalog.api:
    image: catalogapi
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: src/Services/Catalog.Api/Dockerfile

      depends_on:
        - api.gw

  identity.api:
    image: identityapi
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: src/Services/Identity.Api/Dockerfile

      depends_on:
        - api.gw

  eshop:
    image: eshop
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/eShop/Dockerfile

    depends_on:
      - api.gw
```

But when command 'docker-compose up' started I received a error: 
- docker-compose up
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 13, column 12

Help please. Tell why it was happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `docker-compose.yaml` file was wrong.

Try this

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  api.gw:
    image: ocelotapigw
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/OcelotApiGw/Dockerfile

  catalog.api:
    image: catalogapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Services/Catalog.Api/Dockerfile

    depends_on:
      - api.gw

  identity.api:
    image: identityapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Services/Identity.Api/Dockerfile

    depends_on:
      - api.gw

  eshop:
    image: eshop
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/eShop/Dockerfile

    depends_on:
      - api.gw
```

*NOTE: `build`, `image` and `depends_on` field should be aligned properly.*

To verify syntax of `docker-compose.yaml` make use of [docker-compose config](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/config/) command.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml config
```